# Android App Inspection crashes my application

Tags: android-studio

Im trialing Android Studio beta version

```
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Beta 4
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.7905991, built on November 11, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.15.7
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 12
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.6.0-release-798-AS7442.40)
```

Im experiencing this intermittent exception

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: canceled due to java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.nextId() (tried Java_com_android_tools_profiler_support_network_HttpTracker_00024Connection_nextId and Java_com_android_tools_profiler_support_network_HttpTracker_00024Connection_nextId__)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:530)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.nextId() (tried Java_com_android_tools_profiler_support_network_HttpTracker_00024Connection_nextId and Java_com_android_tools_profiler_support_network_HttpTracker_00024Connection_nextId__)
        at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.nextId(Native Method)
        at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.<init>(HttpTracker.java:209)
        at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.<init>(HttpTracker.java:201)
        at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker.trackConnection(HttpTracker.java:294)
        at com.android.tools.profiler.agent.okhttp.OkHttp3Interceptor.trackRequest(OkHttp3Interceptor.java:84)
        at com.android.tools.profiler.agent.okhttp.OkHttp3Interceptor.intercept(OkHttp3Interceptor.java:45)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt:222)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
                ... 3 more
```

My guess is that this exception is caused by the App Inspection feature of AS.

Why does it crash my application though?